# Send Wordpress current user to laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, authentication

I have a front with wordpress (e-commerce) im trying to get the current authentified user ID to my laravel backend application ( with cookies,session ) so far no luck , does anyone have an idea how
Thanks.
N : both applications are in same domain  back.mysite.com (Laravel), mysite.com (wordpress) !

Comment: This is not that straight forward as you think . You might be needing to use API, Observers. Webhooks etc.

Comment: There no api that can retrieve user id i'm already using woocommerce api , but i think cookie may be a possible solution !